# how to iterate over ponyorm entity object

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, ponyorm

I am using ponyORM and i make query to the PeopleModel" for example:

```
first_name = "avi"
sqlObject = select(p for p in PeopleModel if raw_sql('( lower(first_name) = lower($first_name))
```

sqlObject object return the list of PeopleModel as expected and its perfect. 
Now i want to print all PeopleModel values, i expect to something like that to work:

```
for people_model_key,people_model_value in sqlObject.items():
    print(people_model_value)
```

But it doesn't working..

How could i print all the people_model values ? 
Thank you vert much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `select` function is a query object:

```py
first_name = "avi"
people = select(p for p in PeopleModel
                if raw_sql('( lower(first_name) = lower($first_name))
```

It is not a dictionary, so it does not have `items` method. If you iterate over it, you will get objects. You can access objects attributes in a usual way:

```
for person in people:
    print('name:', person.name)
    print('age:', person.age)
```

If you want to convert object to a dictionary, you can use [`to_dict`](https://docs.ponyorm.com/api_reference.html#Entity.to_dict) method:

```
for person in people:
    for key, value in person.to_dict().items():
        print(key, value)
```